# Jquery UI DatePicker not working - jsfiddle included

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

you will have to expand the "run" pane so you can see the whole date picker.

Pick a date with the first picker. Then go to pick a date with the second. It's trying to prevent you from picking a later date rather than an earlier one. Funny thing is I copied the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range) directly, and the demo works....

http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/KKhZg/3/

Also does not work using 1.5.1 which is the version used in the demo
http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/KKhZg/5/

Version that uses the same exact script and link calls for jquery as the demo. still works wrong.
http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/KKhZg/6/

Comment: I found the issue while using chrome, but it seems to do the same thing on ie8.

Comment: Are you using `/1.5.1/jquery.min.js` or higher or lower? version ?how about ur ui version?

Comment: well the jsfiddle example is using 1.6.0. However I think I was using 1.4.4 when I noticed the problem but I just updated my own code to 1.6.0. so it seems not to matter. Similar with UI version. The jsfiddle example is using 1.8.12

Comment: @val You can see the versions being used in the jsfiddle code block

Comment: jsfiddle updated to use the same jquery, jqueryui and jquery theme as my code.

Comment: Have you tried actually downloading the jquery libaries instead of using the google ones? Maybe there is something wrong with the versions they have. I am not seeing any differences in the demo and yours either.

Comment: ya when my code was using 1.4.4 or something like that it was the downloaded version, but the jquery-ui datepicker demo uses the google ones.

Comment: can someone confirm that they can reproduce so I know it's not my computer?

Comment: I copied the jquery demo to fiddle and it worked but the only difference I saw was the different IDs you changed. Was there anything else?

Comment: @jmein he also said he copy and pasted his code yet the ID's have changed, he has obviously mixed and matched what he wants too I copied and pasted from the demo the code on js fiddle it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/KKhZg/8/

Comment: no that was it, i was trying to use ids that were a little more meaningful... didn't think that would throw it off. So you got it to work correctly? or incorrectly?

Comment: I heard that on version 1.6 is not stable read it on a ticket somewhere on jquery forum and people were discouraged from using it... thats why I asked about the version

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/KKhZg/10/ made it work with the changed ids. The issue was the line `var option = this.id == "fromDate" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",` the `fromDate` Seems like there should be a better way to do that rather than stating the ID twice, once when creating the datepicker and once when setting the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. You also need to change the from in the following line to your new ID:

```
var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",

var option = this.id == "fromDate" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
```

Comment: yup, I noticed that: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/KKhZg/10/ works with the new ids. Seems you should be able to say something like `$(this).data("fromField")` to get the id of the input rather than having that id in two places.